# Two Internship in One Summer?

Tags: job-offer, internship

I interviewed with two different firms for internships this upcoming summer. I received an offer from one, and didn't hear back from the other. So I accepted the offer and moved on.

However, the second firm has now called me to make me an offer for this summer. I am extremely interested in working for the second firm (more excited than for the first one), and I would love to accept the offer. I don't want to renege, I know it's bad.

Is it possible to work two internships in one summer, one after another? How would I handle this logistically? My summer break is 15 weeks long.

Comment: Is it possible?  It depends on the internship.  If you're expected to be physically present at two different buildings during normal business hours, not unless you have discovered how to clone yourself.  If you'll be working remotely with flexible hours, it may be possible but it's probably going to be rather exhausting.

Comment: Did you verbally accept the first offer, or have you signed a contract?  Reneging on a verbal agreement is not that big of a deal; it's not official until you sign on the line.

Comment: lol, that edit just negated my entire answer. if it's possible to do both, that's up to you.  We can't really make that decision for you.

Answer (score 3):

If the internships are consecutive, not concurrent, then yes, it should be possible. You should verify the start and end dates of both internships before accepting the second. If they overlap, you'll have to decide what you want to do.

You might prepare for events like the first internship asking you to stay longer (to complete a project, for example, or to attend a wrap-up event), or the second internship offering events prior to the start date that you won't be able to attend.